# Bootstrap columns - 3 columns with center columns maximizing size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a template where I have 3 columns on the same row:

- first column adjust to its content (a picture / avatar)
- third column adjust to its content (a date or time)
  and the second column contains a sentence, and takes all remaining space. If the text is too long, I want it broken so that the second column does not get too big and creates a second row.

I tried this
https://codepen.io/chris-eykm/pen/zYZmRKe

```
<div class="row" style="width: 24rem; border: 1px solid gray">
  <div class="col"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/thecatalystnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/OPINION_avatar_XixiQin.png?resize=48%2C50&ssl=1"/></div>
  <div class="col-auto">Mister Green</div>
  <div class="col">13.06.2021</div>
</div>
```

However I can't achieve this: if the text is too long, it keep increasing the size of the column until it takes 100% of its parent, and is shown on a separate row.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a col-span on the large text to force its restriction to only take upo a part of the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using col-auto on the wrong elements, use them on the other two and leave the one in the middle as col. Also include flex-nowarp on the row so it doesnt force a wrap

```html
<div class="row flex-nowrap" style="width: 24rem; border: 1px solid gray">
  <div class="col-auto"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/thecatalystnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/OPINION_avatar_XixiQin.png?resize=48%2C50&ssl=1"/></div>
  <div class="col">Mister Green has been in the Tavern of Oblivion</div>
  <div class="col-auto">13.06.2021</div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, works like a charm! I was indeed mixed-up :-)